# How to access Form class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When in c# we add any new windows form than that form is by default inherited from the Form class so I want to see this Form class and i want to change something in that by default Form class for my project. 
 So, Where is this Form class and how i can change it?

I have lots of forms. and all the forms' load event and resize event contains the following code.

```
private void frmBranchDetails_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - panel1.Width) / 2;
    panel1.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - panel1.Height) / 2;
}

private void frmBranchDetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

So I want to write the above code only once in the inbuilt Form class which is inherited when we add any new form. 
So don't write the above code repeatedly in all the window form. 
So i want when i add any new form then the above code is automatically added because any form is inherited by default Form class. So i want to write the above code in the Form class.
But where this default Form class and how to write the above code in that class don't know so this is my question.

Comment: We are missing a lot of details here to be of help. How do you add the new forms, and where do you expect to find them?

Comment: I think what you want to do is not the correct way to think about it. Your form's class inherits the `Form` class so that you can re-implement `Form`'s functions where necessary. So, you never need to change any of `Form`'s code.

Comment: Sorry, for my bad method to ask a question.

Comment: Tell us please, why do you want to change it. Or better say what you are trying to do. You may think wrong of how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my question and try to ask with better understanding. Really sorry, for my bad way for asking a question.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change anything in `System.Windows.Forms`. But what you can do is:

1. Create a parentForm inherited from `System.Windows.Forms`.

   ```
   public partial class ParentForm: System.Windows.Forms
   ```
2. Add the functions you need additionally in `ParentForm`.
3. Create all other forms inheriting from this `ParentForm`. Like:

   ```
   public partial class NewForm: ParentForm
   ```

That is the beauty of inheritance.

**EDIT:**

For your problem:

Create a ParentForm like:

```
public partial class baseForm : Form
{
    public baseForm()
    {
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormLoad); 
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.frmBranchDetails_Resize);        
    }
    protected virtual void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)         
    {             
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;         
    }

    private void frmBranchDetails_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - panel1.Width) / 2;
        panel1.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - panel1.Height) / 2;
    }
}
```

NB: The `panel1` should be created in the `baseForm` in order to access it.

Then create your `NewForm` form like:

```
public partial class NewForm: baseForm
{
}
```

Now the `NewForm` form already has the both of those functions.

Comment: 'public partial class Base : Form
{
    public Base()
    {
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormLoad);
    }
    protected virtual void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
}'

Comment: @user3216114: You want to add these two functions, right? I will edit my answer.

Comment: I am using the above my comments' code                                    `public partial class NewForm : Base`         Form's load event is created But the how to create resize event in the base class.

Comment: You really shouldn't use events. Override the `OnLoad` and `OnResize` methods instead.

Comment: Hello Raging Bull The following error occurs in class file:  The name 'panel1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user3216114: Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied so that it could help others who come across with this kind of doubt in future.